# Plot a histogram based on the Date class

Tags: r

I was looking around the web but could not find the answer that I' looking for.
Here is my input data:

```
 Date           Calls
 2012-01-01       3
 2012-01-01       3
 2012-01-01       10
 2012-03-02       15
 2012-03-02       7
 2012-03-02       5
 2012-04-02       0
 2012-04-02       5
 2012-04-02       18
 2012-04-02       1
 2012-04-02       0
 2012-05-02       2
```

I want to plot a hist that will have the sum of calls for each of the days in the "Date" column.
Yes, it can be done by identifying the levels of Date column and add up the corresponding Calls but wondering
if as an elegant way to do it. "Date" column is as "Date" data.class().
According to this example, the final hist should have 4 bins of  (16, 27, 24, 2).

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, technically a histogram is really only to estimate the density function of continuous data and the way you have your data coded, it's more like Date is a categorical variable. So you probably just want a bar chart of counts than a true histogram. You can do what with `ggplot` with

```
qplot(Date,Calls, data=dd, stat="summary", fun.y="sum", geom="bar")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: nice.  I was trying to use `stat_sum` but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Read data:

```
d <- read.table(text=
"Date           Calls
2012-01-01       3
2012-01-01       3
2012-01-01       10
2012-03-02       15
2012-03-02       7
2012-03-02       5
2012-04-02       0
2012-04-02       5
2012-04-02       18
2012-04-02       1
2012-04-02       0
2012-05-02       2",
header=TRUE)

d$Date <- as.Date(d$Date)
library(plyr)
s <- ddply(d,"Date",summarize,Calls=sum(Calls))
library(ggplot2)
```

If we use `Date` as the x variable we get month labels:

```
ggplot(s,aes(x=Date,y=Calls))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

You might prefer the particular date labels:

```
ggplot(s,aes(x=factor(Date),y=Calls))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Or non-default labels:

```
ggplot(s,aes(x=format(Date,"%d-%b"),y=Calls))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  labs(x="Date")
```

It should also be possible to do this by constructing your own `hist` object and passing it to `plot.histogram`, but I think this way is easier ...

Comment: Thanks, this is great! But I would like to do it as histogram. I'm working on something right now to create a new data frame:`for (i in levels(factor(activity$Date))){print(sum(activity$Calls[activity$Date == i]))}` and then plot the new frame. just for challenge, I would like it as basic histogram...:)

Comment: by "basic histogram" you mean something that looks like the output of `hist()`?  My answer, and several of the answers linked at the duplicate question, show you how to aggregate more efficiently.  As I said in my answer, you can construct a `hist()` object and plot it with `plot.histogram()`, but it's a bit of a pain -- you have to figure out the breakpoints, midpoints, etc..

Comment: PS I'm sorry I closed the question, possibly a bit prematurely.  You could ask a new question (almost identical) that makes this specification a bit more precise.  It might be helpful to explain **why** you want to make it harder when `ggplot2` makes it so easy ...

Comment: Your answer is great and I appreciate your help. The reason for wanting to do it as "basic histogram" as that I want learn from it by challenging the problem.

Comment: I was able to reopen.  Why don't you edit your question?