# how to plot histogram with a date and a corresponding value to it

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, histogram

I have the following data:

```
    date        total_step
1 2012-10-01    NA
2 2012-10-02   126
3 2012-10-03 11352
4 2012-10-04 12116
5 2012-10-05 13294
6 2012-10-06 15420
```

with total 61 rows and few NA s. "date" column is of Date class and total_steps column is of integer class.
Now I want to plot it with a histogram and not a bar plot, where x axis will correspond to date and y axis will correspond to total_step.

I have seen a similar problem solution for bar plot in the following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716848/plot-a-histogram-based-on-the-date-class

But I am looking for a solution of histogram not bar plot. I know the solution for bar plot.

Please help.

Ok original data is:

```
  steps       date interval
1    NA 2012-10-01        0
2    NA 2012-10-01        5
3    NA 2012-10-01       10
4    NA 2012-10-01       15
5    NA 2012-10-01       20
6    NA 2012-10-01       25
```

with 17568 rows.
Instructions are:
1.Calculate the total number of steps taken per day
2.If you do not understand the difference between a histogram and a barplot, research the difference between them. Make a histogram of the total number of steps taken each day.

I have figured out total number of steps taken per day(instruction 1) in the following format:

```
    date        total_step
1 2012-10-01    NA
2 2012-10-02   126
3 2012-10-03 11352
4 2012-10-04 12116
5 2012-10-05 13294
6 2012-10-06 15420
```

Now about instruction 2 I am a bit lost as I can plot the bar plot, but I am not getting the histogram plot.

Comment: What are you picturing when you say you want a histogram and not a bar plot?  If you've pre-summarized your data as in your example then you will likely use `geom_col` or `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` to create the plot.  You would use `geom_histogram` if you needed ggplot2 to count up the frequencies for each date bin.

Comment: I have pre summarized the data and already used geom_bar(stat = "identity") and created a bar plot. But I am not looking for a solution of bar plot, looking for a solution to create a continuous histogram of date as x axis and total_step as y axis. I am not getting any hint about it from anywhere. It is part of one of my assignment.

Comment: In my assignment it is clearly mentioned not to plot bar plot and to plot histogram. I do not need ggplot2 to count up the frequencies for each date bin. Some hint to my actual problem also will be very helpful.

Comment: If by needing to "plot a histogram" means using `geom_histogram` it would make sense to use unsummarized data.  If it just means creating a frequency plot using bars than `geom_col` seems sufficient; you could add `width = 1` to make the bars all touch each other if that is needed.

Comment: I have re-edited my post with the actual instructions. Can you get my doubt now?

Comment: You might want this (where `df` is the data frame, where you have already summed up the number of steps per day): `ggplot(df, aes(x = total_step)) + geom_histogram()`